# How to derive thermal time constant from a MOSFET's datasheet?

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, temperature, thermal

I use the Vishay [SiA440DJ](https://www.vishay.com/en/product/64138/) MOSFET in a PMSM inverter. For thermal simulation in Maltab/Simscape I need to provide thermal data. On pg. 1 of the datasheet the thermal resistance Junction to ambient = 80 K/W can be found, also junction to case = 6.5 K/W.

1. Is it possible to get the thermal resistance case to ambient by RthJA-RthJC = (80-6.5)*K/W = 73.5 K/W ?

Simscape also needs a thermal time constant or a thermal mass in J/K. My approach is to use the *Normalized Thermal Transient Impedance, Junction-to-Ambient* chart on pg.6 of the datasheet. on the 0.5 duty cycle graph I look for the 63 % point and derive a time of 50 ms. For junction to case I found a time constant of 300 µs.

2. Is that correct? To me it seems a little too fast to heat up a 1 sq. inch area of PCB with the MOSFET on it within 50 ms?!

Comment: I don't think you're using the transient thermal impedance graph correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vishay didn't link this to the FET but they offer a separate datasheet for the thermal characterstics [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/69893/sia440dj_rc.pdf). i found all the information I need.
I guess another approach would be to use a curve fitting technique and reproduce the curve by R and C elements.